# How to best run Symfony Messenger Worker on Kubernetes

Tags: symfony, deployment, kubernetes, symfony4, symfony-messenger

What's the best way to run the `messenger:consume` task on Kubernetes?

**Deployment?**

If we do it with a deployment with a certain number of replicas this could work, but what if we do a rolling update of the deployment which then results in a pod to be replaced although a long running message is handled by it right now?

To prevent this we could probably set a high `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` and use `lifecycle.preStop` in combination?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: deploy
  name: deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: deploy
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: deploy
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 6000
      containers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - sleep 1d # bin/console messenger:consume
        image: bash
        name: deploy
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - sh
              - -c
              - echo "Test if a message is consumed at the moment and prevent POD shutdown till then?"
```

But during my tests, even if the `lifecycle.preStop` tasks stops early, the full time defined by `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` is still waited till the pod is terminated.

Anyone got a good idea out there?

Comment: `This Component is experimental.` so think twice!

Comment: Experimental AND hot :D But this could also be seen as a Kubernetes issue for any other long running processes in a Deployment.

Comment: it's seems is working as expected. Please refer to [Container hooks execution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) and [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods). I would like suggest to use another approach like blue green deployment.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: agent
spec:
  replicas: 8
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      id: agent-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        id: agent-pod
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600
      containers:
      - name: agent
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /share
            name: share
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["sh", "-c", "touch /tmp/kill_me"]
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - >
          sleep 3 && rm -rf var/cache/* && bin/console cache:clear &&
          while ! [ -f /tmp/kill_me ];
            do
            bin/console messenger:consume queue --limit=1 --time-limit=60 -vv
          done;
        image: my-symfony-agent-image
```

More [here](https://medium.com/@wuestkamp/symfony-messenger-worker-on-kubernetes-77f75725b5ed?source=friends_link&sk=c0a38e15d6cca86ffdec1496c075bacc).